# Problems with BMP{FileHeader, InfoHeader} structures

Tags: c

I want to load a bmp file into memory in C. I've found many different types of BmpFileHeader and BmpInfoHeader structures. The last one that I've taken it from msdn.microsoft.com but it still does not read properly from binary file. With test file [lena](http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp) 
Image Size: -1076791624
Memory could not be allocated

What's the point I am missing? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
  unsigned short bfType;
  unsigned int bfSize;
  short bfReserved1;
  short bfReserved2;
  unsigned int bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
  unsigned int biSize;
  int biWidth;
  int biHeight;
  short biPlanes;
  short biBitCount;
  unsigned int biCompression;
  unsigned int biSizeImage;
  int biXPelsPerMeter;
  int biYPelsPerMeter;
  unsigned int biClrUsed;
  unsigned int biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;   

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   if(argc != 2)
   {
    printf("Usage: %s input.bmp\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
   }

   FILE *filePtr;
   BITMAPFILEHEADER bitmapFileHeader;
   BITMAPINFOHEADER bitmapInfoHeader;
   unsigned char *bitmapImage;
   int imageIdx=0;
   unsigned char tempRGB;

   filePtr = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
   if (filePtr == NULL)
   {
    printf("File could not opened\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    //read the bitmap file header
    fread(&bitmapFileHeader, sizeof(bitmapFileHeader), 1, filePtr);

    if (bitmapFileHeader.bfType !=0x4D42)
    {
    fclose(filePtr);
    printf("Not a bmp file\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    fseek(filePtr, bitmapFileHeader.bfOffBits, SEEK_SET);
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage);
    printf("Image Size: %d\n", bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage);

    if (!bitmapImage)
    {
    free(bitmapImage);
    fclose(filePtr);
    printf("Memory could not be allocated\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    //swap the r and b values to get RGB (bitmap is BGR)
    for (imageIdx = 0; imageIdx < bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage; imageIdx+=3)
    {
    tempRGB = bitmapImage[imageIdx];
    bitmapImage[imageIdx] = bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2];
    bitmapImage[imageIdx + 2] = tempRGB;
    }

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage; i+=3){
    printf("R: %c G: %c B: %c\n", bitmapImage[i], bitmapImage[i + 1], bitmapImage[i + 2]);
    }

    fclose(filePtr); 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The printf format for Image Size should be %u instead of %d because bitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage is an unsigned int. This will prevent the misleading negative image size indication. Use a debugger to look at the contents of the structs after reading them from disk to see if they are being populated correctly. Possibly the compiler is inserting extra padding bytes to make word alignment nice (see bfReserved1/bfReserved2 and biPlanes/biBitCount).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I would do is to find an authoritative statement on the [byte layout](http://atlc.sourceforge.net/bmp.html) of these headers and then, assuming that you want to continue to use the structs that you have defined, add some asserts on the field offsets, for example:

```
assert(offsetof(BITMAPFILEHEADER, bfType) == 0);     // or whatever
assert(offsetof(BITMAPFILEHEADER, bfSize) == 2);     // or whatever
assert(offsetof(BITMAPFILEHEADER, bfOffBits) == 10); // or whatever
etc.
```

Chances are that your use of unsigned int, short, etc plus your compiler options (especially structure packing) might mean that your struct fields do not match the actual BMP file data (in offset, and maybe in length).

Answer (score 0):

Your `bitmapInfoHeader` is **uninitialized**!

That is, you read the `bitmapFileHeader`, and then set the file pointer to where the actual bitmap data should be. But you didn't read the `bitmapInfoHeader`, which contains all the information about the bitmap (dimensions, bpp and etc.)

P.S.
Next time please try do debug your code befure posting the question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've added the line; fread(&bitmapInfoHeader, sizeof(bitmapInfoHeader), 1, filePtr); However the output is; Image Size: 4
R: 0 G: 0 B: 0
R: 0 G: 0 B: 0
The image file is 257.1 kb..Something still wrong

Answer (score 0):

There exist several versions of the BMP file format and most of them differ in the size of the headers. If you want to be able to read all valid BMP files, you'll need to support them all. The lena image seems to be a Windows V3 version.

There's a good description of the different versions in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).

Furthermore, I don't see no endianness handling in your code. If you're machine isn't little endian, it will not work.

Finally, the alignment of the struct members is a problem. Your compiler will most likely align the *bfSize* member at offset 4 but it should be at offset 2. (See the Wikipedia article for a solution.)